# Is it possible to access JobParameters knowing the job (execution) ID outside?

Tags: spring-batch

Suppose I want to build an API for (1) submitting jobs to be executed and (2) later get their result/status.

Now, the submit endpoint receives a payload and some headers. The payload is persisted through a custom JpaRepository and the headers are pushed into an instance of JobParameters (which is then fed to the JobLauncher). From what I know so far, there is a JobRepository that will end up persisting my JobParameters.

A. My first question on this design would be: should the JobRepository be used to persist the job payload instead of doing it in a custom JpaRepository?

B. I want access the JobParameters of a certain job (by job ID, which is given back when a job is submitted to the JobLauncher, through the JobExecution; this is standard Spring Batch stuff).

Is this possible from a normal bean (a @Service class)?

- The JobRepository does not expose anything that access a job id and returns the job parameters associated with that.
- There is a [JobExecutionDao](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/JobExecutionDao.html#getJobExecution-java.lang.Long-) that, given an execution ID, could give me access to the JobParameters, but I cannot inject that into my beans.

> Parameter <#> of constructor in  required a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JobExecutionDao' that
>   could not be found.

Comment: This does not qualify as an answer, but from codecentric's (no affiliation) `batch-web-spring-boot-starter` https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-starter-batch-web/blob/master/batch-web-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/de/codecentric/batch/web/JobMonitoringController.java you should be able to glean the relevant API (and then post the answer yourself).

Comment: What does the request payload contain?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your questions and then give you an idea about how I would do it.

> A. My first question on this design would be: should the JobRepository be used to persist the job payload instead of doing it in a custom JpaRepository?

It depends on the request payload. The job repository should be enough to store job meta-data.

> B. I want access the JobParameters of a certain job (by job ID, which is given back when a job is submitted to the JobLauncher, through the JobExecution; this is standard Spring Batch stuff).

Given a job execution id, you can get the parameters using [JobOperator#getParameters(Long executionId)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/JobOperator.html#getParameters-long-)

Now the following is how I would implement your requirement:

> Suppose I want to build an API for (1) submitting jobs to be executed and (2) later get their result/status.

- The API controller receives the name of the job to launch + job parameters and launches the job in a background thread using [an asynchronous job launcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer). This launcher immediately returns the job execution, so the API can return its ID to the caller (without waiting for the job to finish.
- [JobExplorer#getJobExecution(Long executionId)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html#getJobExecution-java.lang.Long-) can be used later on to inspect the job execution status/result
- [JobOperator#getParameters(Long executionId)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/JobOperator.html#getParameters-long-) can be used to retrieve the parameters used to launch the job